# React render an empty component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5, react-dom

i am using react in ES5 syntax, but i a getting a weird behavior

```
TestCom = React.createClass( {render: function() {return React.createElement('div', null, ['asdasd']) }} )

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('TestCom', {}), document.getElementById('matches'));
```

will output

```
<testcomp data-reactroot=""></testcomp>
```

what am i missing ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the component itself, not its name:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(TestCom, {}), document.getElementById('matches'));
```